# Using TestCafe with mobx

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, mobx, testcafe

I am trying to use [testCafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe) and [testcafe react selectors](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors) with my mobx app for end to end testing. React selectors have very convenient selectors. For eg: for components as follows:

```
<TodoApp className="todo-app">
    <TodoInput />
    <TodoList>
        <TodoItem priority="High">Item 1</TodoItem>
        <TodoItem priority="Low">Item 2</TodoItem>
    </TodoList>

    <div className="items-count">Items count: <span>{this.state.itemCount}</span></div>
</TodoApp>
```

Selecting a component is as easy as:

`const TodoList = ReactSelector('TodoApp TodoList')`

But when I am using inject with mobx:

```
inject((ctx) => ({
  injectable1: ctx.injectable1,
}))(Component)
```

there mobx inserts a decorator component like follows:
[image: inject]

Thus I cannot use normal react selector. Is there some way I can use the react selector without using Html selector?

Answer (score 1):

At present, TestCafe (v1.10) does not support this scenario out of the box. So, CSS selectors are the only way to implement your task.

See also: [TestCafe Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/)